# Need help in understanding a solution regarding divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I found this question in the mathematical circles textbook which asked if a number with a hundred 0's , hundred 1's and hundred 2's be a perfect square. As of a solution they pointed out that the number was divisible by 3 but not by 9 no matter how the digits appeared.

I did get that but could not see the connection of it with perfect squares although i am familiar that perfect squares have an odd no. of divisors

Comment: How can a square be divisible by 3 but not 9?

Comment: $$3|n^2 \implies 3|n \implies 9|n^2$$ 3 is square-free.